Import \leftrightwavearrow from MdSymbol
I want to import a single character from the mdsymbol package. I'm well-aware of the font importing guide, but I've still been struggling to put everything together.
After trying to put different code snippets together for an hour, I ended up with a piece of code that seems to work within Overleaf.
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MdSymbolC}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MdSymbolC}{m}{n}{<-6> MdSymbolC-Light5 <6-7> MdSymbolC-Light6 <7-8> MdSymbolC-Light7 <8-9> MdSymbolC-Light8 <9-10> MdSymbolC-Light9 <10-12> MdSymbolC-Light10 <12-> MdSymbolC-Light12}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{arrows}{U}{MdSymbolC}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftrightwavearrow}{\mathrel}{arrows}{"92}

\begin{document}
    $\leftrightwavearrow$
\end{document}

However, it fails on my machine with the following error code

Font U/MdSymbolC/m/n/10=MdSymbolC-Light10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.

I'm on Windows using MikTeX + TeXWorks.

I get no error from your code. The error must lie somewhere else, becaus MdSymbolC-Regular is referenced.

@egreg Do all of the font sizes exist? I don't know if 5, 6, 7, ... etc. is the correct list to load. If so, I can try to make a MWE that fails.

The error code referencing MdSymbolC-Regular was a mistake, I copied an error from another attempt.

so you have no problem to solve?

The problem is that this code snippet which seemingly works in one place doesn't work in another.

there is no problem with the code that you have shown, so if you want help with the code that does not work, please edit the example so that it generates an error.

@ViHdzP When I ran your code, the metric files for the fonts were generated. What platform are on?

I'm on Windows using TexWorks. I just realized that my code works on Overleaf, but not on my own machine. Editing my question to reflect that.

in particular the code posted will not use this font MdSymbolC-Light12 at 14.4pt  so it could not make the error shown, but it will use that font if you put \Large at the start.

I've updated the question with the actual error.

I'd just try with \DeclareFontShape{U}{MdSymbolC}{m}{n}{<-> MdSymbolC-Light}{}

@egreg That worked! Thanks :)

@egreg I guess you should post an answer, miktex doesn't have mktexmf ?

The fonts are actually available in just one optical size.
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MdSymbolC}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MdSymbolC}{m}{n}{ <-> MdSymbolC-Light }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{arrows}{U}{MdSymbolC}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftrightwavearrow}{\mathrel}{arrows}{"92}

\begin{document}

$A \leftrightwavearrow B$

$A \to B$

\end{document}


